# Mismatch between raster displayed in QGIS animation and Temporal Control settings

Tags: pyqgis, time, temporal-controller

I downloaded hourly rainfall in raster format from a French weather forecasting model (AROME). Each raster represents the predicted precipitation over the following time window: raster_name-1h to raster_name. For example, raster 20220929010000 corresponds to precipitation that fell between 2022-09-29 at 00h and 2022-09-29 at 1h.

I want to make a rainfall animation using QGIS Temporal Controller. To avoid having to manually modify the parameters of each layer, I wrote a python script which does it automatically from the name of the raster layers. Concretely, the script activates the Temporal Control of the layer and defines the start and end date of display according to the name of the layer.

Here is the code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

n = layer.name()

year = int(n[0:4])
month = int(n[4:6])
day = int(n[6:8])
hour = int(n[8:10])

start_time = QDateTime(year, month, day, hour+1, 0, 0, Qt.LocalTime)
end_time = QDateTime(year, month, day, hour+1, 59, 0, Qt.LocalTime)
time_range = QgsDateTimeRange(start_time, end_time)

m = layer.metadata()
e = m.Extent()
e.setTemporalExtents([time_range])
m.setExtent(e)
layer.setMetadata(m)

layer.temporalProperties().setIsActive(True)
layer.temporalProperties().setMode(QgsRasterLayerTemporalProperties.ModeFixedTemporalRange)
layer.temporalProperties().setFixedTemporalRange(time_range)
```

Everything seems to work fine, except that when I scroll the animation there is a 2h lag between the displayed raster and the animation time. I wonder if the problem would not come from an automatic convesion of the dates of the local time zone to UTC time (2h lag in France). I changed Qt.LocalTime to Qt.UTC but it didn't help.

Here is an example:

Raster 20220929010000 corresponds to precipitation that fell between 2 a.m. and 3 a.m. on 2022-09-29. The raster is not displayed between 2 a.m. and 3 a.m., but is displayed between midnight and 1 a.m.

[image: Correct not working animation range]

[image: Adjusted working animation range]

However, the Temporal Control of the layer is well set to 2h and 3h (2h59 exactly).

[image: Temporal Control]

What is strange is that the Temporal Extent remains on midnight and 1h (0h59 exactly), hence my doubt on the UTC localtime conversion.

[image: Temporal Extent]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it really is a bigger problem connected to the handling of time zones in Qt/QGIS: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/38647

I changed my systems time zone setting to GMT and the problem was "solved" - at least temporary.